# SQL update based off another table

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, sql-update

I've been looking through several posts but have been unable to get my head around how to achieve the following in PostgreSQL

```
Table 1
---------

USER_ID    NAME
1          User
2          Test

Table 2
--------

USER_ID    WIDGET_ID   WIDGET_CONFIG
1              1             abc
1              2             def
2              1             abc
2              2             def
```

I have 2 tables, what I require is

- Select from table 1, Where the users name = "Test"
- Using that ID ( 2 ) select the widget with a USER_ID of 2, and a WIDGET_ID of 2
- Update the widget_config to be "ghi" for example

I've been getting myself in a twist using the WITH statements perhaps in completely the wrong way

```
WITH res AS ( 
    SELECT agent_id FROM tbl_agent WHERE agentlogin_id='2man'
)

SELECT tbl_agentwidgetconfig
WHERE agent_id=res.agent_id AND widget_id=5;

// Update record code?
```

If anyone could shed some light on the correct way to do this it would be much appreciated!

Comment: POSTGRESQL and MYSQL are not the same Why have you tagged both?

Comment: Specify the expected result as well.

Comment: A simple JOIN is probably what you want.

Comment: @jarlh the result is just an update of the record specified, and and example would be very helpful

Comment: So you have **two** tables. I count three, with **five** different names: {table1,table2, tbl_agent, widget_config,tbl_agentwidgetconfig}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this

```
UPDATE tbl_agentwidgetconfig 
SET widget_config='hij'
WHERE agent_id=any(
  SELECT agent_id FROM tbl_agent
  WHERE agent_loginid='2man')
AND widget_id=5;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are describing something like this?

```
UPDATE
    aw
SET
    WIDGET_CONFIG = 'ghi'
FROM
    tbl_agent a
    INNER JOIN tbl_agentwidgetconfig aw ON aw.USER_ID = a.USER_ID
WHERE
    a.NAME = 'Test'
    AND aw.WIDGET_ID = 2;
```

Comment: This is not valid for Postgres

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via subquery as well:

```
UPDATE table2 
SET WIDGET_CONFIG = 'ghi'
WHERE WIDGET_ID = 2 AND USER ID = (SELECT USER_ID FROM table1 WHERE NAME = 'Test');
```